# mariadb with mysql causes error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I had mysql database with very important data , after that I followed one linux lesson and I copied the command which was about installing mariaDB. After the command was executed I can no longer access mysql with the mysql username and password without using `sudo`

```
sudo mysql -uroot -proot
```

But when logged on I am logged in to maria db and cannot find my database when using the command:

```
use mydb
```

the database is not found..

```
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

How to switch to mysql and access my database again?

Comment: At least on Debian MariaDB is considered the successor of MySQL. So it is likely that you actually "upgraded" your MySQL installation rather than installing MariaDB in parallel. However, MariaDB is binary compatible with MySQL and should be able to read your old database files. Is there still data ("mydb") in your data dir (`/var/lib/mysql/` by default)?

Comment: what You see when call: `show databases;` ? what's inside `/var/lib/mysql` ?

Comment: check my answer, if You'll not succeed contact me in skype: `anarjafarov`

Comment: I found database some where whıch marıadb moved it , but when I removed mariadb and installed mysql again and copied database folder to mysql folder and pressed on table I have 1146 error which say table xxx not exists

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not visible because of it's not defined in `information.SCHEMA_TABLES`

To define it try following steps:

1) make sure that `/var/lib/mysql/mydb` folder does not exist, if exist then:

> 1.1) shutdown mysql
>
> 1.2) delete `/var/lib/mysql/mydb` folder
>
> 1.3) start mysql

2) login to mysql and execute: `CREATE DATABASE mydb;`

3) shutdown mysql

4) copy data files to `/var/lib/mysql/mydb` and define owner:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/mydb
chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/mysql/mydb
chmod 0660 /var/lib/mysql/mydb/*
```

5) start mysql